# Display a sweet alert on Ajax Woocommerce Add To Cart Validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I am trying to display a sweet alert (javascript) on the shop archive page when the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` is triggered...

**Javascript Sweet Alert Doesn't trigger:**

```
// remove the page error redirect
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', '__return_false');

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'restrict_items_in_cart' );

 function restrict_items_in_cart($cart_item_data) {

   global $woocommerce;
   $item_count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;

    //IF CONDITION TO VALIDATE CART
   if($item_count > 1){

     //JAVASCRIPT ALERT TO BE DISPLAYED. BUT DOES NOT TRIGGER
     ?>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.20.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                  swal(
                    'TOO MANY ITEMS!',
                    'Want to change?',
                    'error')
        </script>
<?php

   }
   return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Items are being added to the cart on the shop/archive page via AJAX...Any idea why the javascript wont trigger for the function? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon further inspection, items which are being "validated" are still called with the ajax `added_to_cart`. Therefore the same logic can be used where jQuery code will send an ajax request on "added_to_cart" delegated event. On that request php will get the *number of attempts a cart item has been added to the basket* and will return it to jQuery. If that count has met a condition, it will display sweet-alert message:

Thanks to @LoicTheAztec for helping provide part of the solution.

```
// remove the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', '__return_false'); 

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'restrict_only_one_item_in_cart' );

 function restrict_only_one_item_in_cart($cart_item_data) {

   global $woocommerce;
   $item_count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;

   if($item_count >= 20)
   {
      //WE WILL EXECUTE JAVASCRIPT BELOW INSTEAD
      return false;
   }

   return $cart_item_data;
}

// The Jquery script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_full' );
function cart_full() {
    ?>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.20.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        // The Ajax function
        $(document.body).on('added_to_cart', function() {
            console.log('event');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'checking_cart_items',
                    'added' : 'yes'
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if( response >= 20 ){
                        swal(
                            'Youve added the max items!',
                            'Change Your box',
                            'error'
                        );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```